Oracle Service Bus Error: The Business Service call is not returning the result in JSON format
I created a REST Adapter in the Business Service, configuring it with the external service URL, credentials, and JSON payload body. However, when I run this business service directly from OSB Service Bus, it results in an error.
The error message includes hexadecimal values (e.g., 00000000: 7B 21 71 72 60 55 12 7A 88 12 34 74 70 73 3A 2F), and is not in proper JSON format. Despite configuring the REST Adapter with JSON for both request and response payloads, the issue persists.
When calling the external service from SOAPUI, the error message appears in JSON format without hexadecimal values, which indicates that the external service returns a response with the content type application/problem+json.
Please advise on how to handle this content type in OSB or if any adjustments are needed to correctly process and interpret the error response.
Kindly note that I have only added BS not pipeline nothing

Not enough info has been provided to resolve this. Try calling the external service using Postman. Looks like the response is being converted to hex. However, converting back shows garbled text, so could be any number of things. Call it with Postman and post the response here. Did you set any properties in the business service or use all defaults?
